# Is the set of binary sequences with no consecutive ones countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A binary sequence is an infinite list of zeroes and ones, ie, $b$ is a binary sequence means that $b = b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_i,...,$ where each $b_i \in \{0,1\}$. Let $C$ be the subset of $B$ containing only those sequences that have no consecutive ones.  Decide whether or not C is countable.

My attempt:

Consider an element $c_i \in C$ and its sequence of digits in a decimal expansion, perhaps $0.1010101.$ Although there may be no consecutive ones, there may be infinitely many ones. Thus another element $c_{i+1}$ and its sequence could be $0.1010101$. The only way a certain $c_n$ couldn't belong in $C$ is if it had at least two 1's next to each other, which simply can't be the case. This makes $C$ countably infinite.

Comment: comment deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are wrong, $C$ is uncountable. And it's not that hard to define injective function $f:B\to C$. For instance you could insert $0$ between every consecutive digits in each sequence from $B$. Now knowing that $B$ is uncountable, $C$ is also uncountable by Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder theorem.

**Edit:**
You are not removing anything. We got injection from $B$ into $C$, so $|B|\leq|C|$, which is already sufficient to conclude that $C$ is uncountable, as $B$ is uncountable. But also $|C|\leq|B|$, as $C\subset B$, hence $|B|=|C|$. And just to be precise $f$ can by defined by:
$$
f(b)(n) =
\begin{cases}
b\left(\frac n2\right),  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
0, & \text{if $n$ is odd}  \\
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: AHA! So I have to consider removing the finite set from the infinite set. Correct?

Comment: @DonLarynx:  no, you are not removing anything.  He is showing how to establish a bijection between $B$ and $C$ by showing you have an injection both ways.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Cantor diagonal argument to show that all of the sequences with blocks 00 and 01 are uncountable.  Examples of these block sequences:

0100010001....... 
00000101000001.....

NO:

1000.....

These form a subset of the set you are asking about.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive integers. Define $S(a)\in C$ by
$$
S(a)=(0)_{a_1}1(0)_{a_2}1(0)_{a_3}1\dots,
$$
where $(0)_k$ means $k$ consecutive $0$'s. $S$ is an injection from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ into $C$, so that $C$ is uncountable.

Comment: Oh, so it's simply all of the binary sequences but listed consecutively, isn't it @Julian?

Comment: I do not understand your comment. My construction assigns to each sequence of positive integers a unique binary sequence without consecutive ones.

Comment: But it's still infinite, meaning every binary sequence shall be included. @Julian

Answer (score 1):

A hint:

Consider the subset $C'\subset C$ consisting of the sequences beginning with $1$, having infinitely many ones and only $1$ or $2$ zeros between consecutive ones. Recode the sequences $b\in C'$ in a way that makes the anser to your problem immediately apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cantor's diagonal proof with adjustment:

Observe two consecutive bits as a pair, you'll find that those bits belong to the set {01, 10, 00} . Put { 01, 10 } to group A and { 00 } to group B, and then your sequence will be ABBABA....... something like that. Ready for diagonal proof!

Thanks hardmath for pointing out the mistakes. I know that there is an accepted answer, just providing another method to deal with this problem.

Comment: oh sorry my bad...