# Proving that there are as many infinite binary sequences and infinite binary sequences not containing 11

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that all the infinite binary sequence are equal in cardinality to the infinite binary sequences which don't include 1 twice in a row. And I'm supposed to use Cantor-Schrodder-Bernstein.

Finding an injection from the sequences not containing 1 twice in a row to all the sequences is trivial, but how do I go about finding an injection in the other direction?

Comment: See also [Is the set of binary sequences with no consecutive ones countable?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531072/is-the-set-of-binary-sequences-with-no-consecutive-ones-countable).

Comment: Call the set of binary sequences $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ and the set without multiple $1$s in a row $\{0,10\}^{\mathbb N}$. Does this suggest a bijection? (Also, double-check that my last thing actually is the set of them without multiple $1$s in a row.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cantor-Bernstein sounds like a good idea.

How about encoding `1` as `01` and `0` as `001`? Or simply sticking in a `0` 
after every `1`?

(Actually, unless I'm much mistaken, I think sticking in a `0` after every `1` will give you a *bijection* right away).

Comment: Yes, the unix line `sed s/1/10/g` can be used in a math proof :)